# (Gantt-like) timeline visualization library? (JavaScript/JQuery or .NET)

Tags: javascript, .net, visualization, timeline, gantt-chart

Suppose I have a collection of records structured as following:

```
MyEvent { 
    int Id;
    string EventName;  
    string EventCategory;
    DateTime Start;
    DateTime End;
}
```

...what libraries *(either JavaScript/JQuery or .NET)* are worth checking if I wish to:

- ...visualize the collection in a 'gantt-like' timeline, in which the bars are organized by 'Event Category' and the blocks labeled (or, perhaps, colourized) by 'Event Name'?
- ...scroll and zoom through said timeline?

**Note:** Minimal footprint is key here! The visualization is merely for diagnostic purposes so a simple (preferably open source) solution will suffice!

Answer (score 1):

Try RadiantQ's jQuery Gantt Package: http://radiantq.com/products/jquery-gantt-package/jquery-gantt-package-features/

Lets you categorize in many different ways, colorize, label, time-line zooming, etc.

Plenty of samples and you can get a prototype put together from them once you share your sample data.

Disclaimer: I do work for RadiantQ